# Keep old object without changing it

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following code and In RT when *mappingObject* is updated *oldObjToDel* is updated accordingly, but my question is :
Is there a way to keep the *oldObjToDel* with the first reference without changing it like it happens after calling to the *updateReferance* method ? I want *oldObjToDel* to keep the object before changing it in *UpdateReferance*...

```
private bool UpdateMapping(out  MappingFields oldObjToDel)
{
    MappingFields mappingObject = GetMappingLabelObject(textbox.Name);
    oldObjToDel = mappingObject;
    isAdded = UpdateReferance(  mappingObject);
}

internal class MappingFields
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public bool isFound { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this automatically in the general case. You need to make a copy (clone) of the object, which would be independent of its "source".

If your object only has scalar fields then you can utilize [`object.MemberwiseClone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); otherwise, you should consider implementing [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ICloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and supply an implementation of `Clone` with appropriate semantics. The documentation for `MemberwiseClone` also lists several alternatives:

> There are numerous ways to implement a deep copy operation if the
>   shallow copy operation performed by the MemberwiseClone method does
>   not meet your needs. These include the following:
>
> - Call a class
>     constructor of the object to be copied to create a second object with
>     property values taken from the first object. This assumes that the
>     values of an object are entirely defined by its class constructor.
> - Call the MemberwiseClone method to create a shallow copy of an object,
>     and then assign new objects whose values are the same as the original
>     object to any properties or fields whose values are reference types.
>     The DeepCopy method in the example illustrates this approach.
> - Serialize the object to be deep copied, and then restore the
>     serialized data to a different object variable.
> - Use reflection with
>     recursion to perform the deep copy operation.

**Update:**

Since your implementation of `MappingFields` only uses string and boolean fields, `MemberwiseClone` will do the job. First expose a `Clone` method:

```
internal class MappingFields : ICloneable
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public bool isFound { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

}
```

and then call it:

```
oldObjToDel = (MappingFields)mappingObject.Clone();
```

Comment: Hi jon can you please provide example?

Comment: @JeanTehhe: There are many ways to do this and lots of factors go into the decision. At the very least you would need to show what `MappingFields` is.

Comment: when I try your proposal I got error in MemberwiseClone();cannot access protected method 'MemberwiseClone()' here , any idea?

Comment: @JeanTehhe: See the current version :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to create a clone of the original object easily. I guess [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper) could give some idea on how to do it. You could also check [AutoMapper getting started](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) page.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Can you please provide example?

Comment: Check my edited answer. I put some tutorials regarding Automapper.